# Packets dropping cisco 6509

Tags: networking, cisco, tcp

so I am having frequent network drops/latency on a trunk between a two cisco 6509's one runing IOS the other running Catos. The catos is showing some counter errors that I believe to be the issue

```
0  rxCRCAlignErrors                   =          9
1  rxUndersizedPkts                   =          0
2  rxOversizedPkts                    =          0
3  rxFragmentPkts                     =        396
4  rxJabbers                          =       1596
5  txCollisions                       =          0
6  ifInErrors                         =       2001
7  ifOutErrors                        =          0
8  ifInDiscards                       =          0
9  ifInUnknownProtos                  =          0
10 ifOutDiscards                      =          0
11 txDelayExceededDiscards            =          0
12 txCRC                              =          0
13 linkChange                         =          0
14 wrongEncapFrames                   =          0
0  dot3StatsAlignmentErrors           =          0
1  dot3StatsFCSErrors                 =          9
2  dot3StatsSingleColFrames           =          0
3  dot3StatsMultiColFrames            =          0
4  dot3StatsSQETestErrors             =          0
5  dot3StatsDeferredTransmisions      =          0
6  dot3StatsLateCollisions            =          0
7  dot3StatsExcessiveCollisions       =          0
8  dot3StatsInternalMacTransmitErrors =          0
9  dot3StatsCarrierSenseErrors        =          0
10 dot3StatsFrameTooLongs             =          0
11 dot3StatsInternalMacReceiveErrors  =          0
12 dot3StatsSymbolErrors              =      15199
0  txPause                            =          0
1  rxPause                            =          0
0  rxTotalDrops                       =      15237
1  rxFIFOFull                         =          0
2  rxBadCode                          =      15199
```

I am not a super experienced at troubleshooting the network side. But where is a good place to start with this. I don't think it is a configuration issue because no configuration has changed. I did notice that this was a port channel with only one fiber cable going over so I switched it to a non port channel, that seems to have helped some but not a complete fix as my counters are still rising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those types of errors almost always mean there is something wrong at the physical level. That includes the fiber transceiver, fiber patch cables, and the structured fiber. It could also be a problem with the line card or a single port on the line card. Try moving the fiber transceiver to a different port on the same card, or a different port on a different line card. Change one thing at a time until you isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks, we are about to just create a seperate copper portchannel and run the traffic over that interface. My thinking was it is a physical issue as well being either. Thanks alot.